# How to to train multi regression output with tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras

Only the first output parameter is learned to be properly estimated during training of a multi regression output net. Second and subsequent parameters only seem to follow first parameter. It seems, that ground truth for second output parameter is not used during training. How do I shape tf.data.Dataset and input it into model.fit() function so second output parameter is trained?

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    import pandas as pd
    from tensorflow import keras
    from keras import layers
    
    #create dataset from csv
    file = pd.read_csv( 'minimalDataset.csv', skipinitialspace = True)
    input = file["input"].values
    output1 = file["output1"].values
    output2 = file["output2"].values
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input, (output1, output2))).batch(4)
    
    #create multi output regression net
    input_layer = keras.Input(shape=(1,))
    x = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(input_layer)
    x = layers.Dense(60, activation="relu")(x)
    output_layer = layers.Dense(2)(x)
    model = keras.Model(input_layer, output_layer)
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")
    
    #train model and make prediction (deliberately overfitting to illustrate problem)
    model.fit(dataset, epochs=500)
    
    prediction = model.predict(dataset)
```

`minimalDataset.csv` and predictions:

| input | output1 | output2 |  | prediction_output1 | prediction_output2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -1 | 1 |  | -0.989956 | -0.989964 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |  | 1.834444 | 1.845085 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 |  | 0.640249 | 0.596099 |
| 3 | 1 | -1 |  | 0.621426 | 0.646796 |

If I create two independent dense final layers the second parameter is learned accurately but I get two losses:

```
output_layer = (layers.Dense(1)(x), layers.Dense(1)(x))
```

Note: I want to use tf.data.Dataset because I build a 20k image/csv with it and do per-element transformations as preprocessing.

Answer (score 0):

tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices() slices along the first dimension. Because of this the input and output tensors need to be transposed:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.transpose(input), (tf.transpose([output1, output2])))).batch(4)
```